# How to disable Safari Power Saver in OSX Mavericks?

Tags: flash, safari, osx-mavericks

How can I disable the new Safari Power Saver, Click to Start Flash Plugin, in OSX Mavericks?

I don't need to disable it for the end user. I just want to disable it for myself when testing the flash content I am developing.

Pretty lame how this feature takes over even if the SWF is the ONLY item on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari / preferences / advanced
uncheck "stop plug-ins to saver power"